# Calling member function on object which is not constructed, C++

Tags: c++, constructor, this, destructor, member-functions

Hence this:

```
class A 
{ 
public: 
    A() 
    { 
        cout << "A() "; 
    } 
    void f() 
    { 
        cout << "f "; 
    } 
    ~A() 
    { 
        cout << "~A() "; 
    } 
};

int  main()
{
    A *p = (A*)2; 
    p->f(); 
}
class A 
{ 
public: 
    A() 
    { 
        cout << "A() "; 
    } 
    void f() 
    { 
        cout << "f "; 
    } 
    ~A() 
    { 
        cout << "~A() "; 
    } 
};

int  main()
{
    A *p = (A*)2; 
    p->f(); 
}
//ouput is 
// f
```

How can a programm call a member function of non existing object?
How the programm passes the this pointer to the function?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. That is how.

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: So this behavior of this code is both compiler and platform dependent?

Comment: Technically, it is *anything* dependent. You can get different results on the same platform and compiler.

Comment: no, it's not compiler and platform dependent, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: So accordingly, calling the function on non initialized pointer in c++ is allowed but it is undefined behavior according to ISO C++?

Comment: Yes, "undefined behaviour" is typically "allowed" by the compiler/language spec (In other wrods, "the compiler is not required to detect it"). But it's undefined, so "anything can happen" - if the compiler decides to generate code to format your hard-drive as a result, then that's within the letter of the specification (if not quite within the spirit, perhaps).

Comment: @EduardRostomyan: Undefined behaviour means that you cannot derive any predictions about the program's behaviour from the rules of the language.

Comment: Try it with a `virtual` function. You'll likely get your desired explosion. As-written the compiler is simply generating a function call, pushing whatever you gave it as `this` (undefined, of course) without the need for virtual fairy dust (really, its magic =P). If you write to a member variable you'll likely get an exciting access violation with a bizarre address, and a little math will explain what is happening. Regardless, its UB.